# "Cannot read property" when using deferConfig of node-config in "TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-config

I'm using [node-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) in TypeScript.
I have the code like below:
`config/default.ts`:

```js
import {deferConfig} from 'config/defer';
export default {
  service: {
    url: 'http://localhost',
    errorUrl: deferConfig(function() {
      console.info('config before defer:', this);
      return `${this['service']['url']}/error.html`;
    }),
  },
};
```

`src/demo.ts`:

```js
import config from 'config';
console.info('resulting config: ', config)
```

It works fine when I run my code with `ts-node`.

```sh
$ npx ts-node ./src/demo.ts
config before defer: { service: { url: 'http://localhost', errorUrl: [Getter] } }
resulting config:  Config {
  service: { url: 'http://localhost', errorUrl: 'http://localhost/error.html' }
}
```

However, if I run the code compiled with `tsc`, I get

```sh
$ NODE_CONFIG_DIR=./build/config ./build/src/demo.js
config before defer: {
  default: { service: { url: 'http://localhost', errorUrl: [Getter] } }
}
.../build/config/default.js:9
            return `${this['service']['url']}/error.html`;
                                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

The value of `this` has an extra level of `default`.
Why the behavior is inconsistent for the ts and the js code?
If I change `export default` to `export =`, it works for both ts and js code.
However, the [document](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files#typescript---ts) of `node-config` asks me to use `export default`.
Should I use `export =` instead?

Comment: where did you print `this` from?

Comment: @tromgy I printed `this` inside the defer function. I've updated the question. I hope it's clearer. :)

Comment: The discrepancy between tsc and ts-node might be due to the "experimental" support for ESM modules in ts-node: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007. But also anonymous default export is considered a bad practice: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.24.2/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md So you can also try something like `const my_config = { /* the object you want to export */ }; export default my_config;` Still, I find it very strange that you get an actual object _named_ "default" as your `this`.

Comment: @tromgy Using named default export doesn't seem to change the result. But thank you for pointing out the best practice.